# How exactly should I use LaTeX instead of word?

Tags: tex-general

I know that this is not a typical question for this website but I guess the answers can be helpful for a lot of new users of Latex.

I'm a PhD student in Chemistry. For the last couple of months I've been trying to get used to Latex. All my research groups uses Word and most people in my department use word.

I've look around the web and a lot of people says that Latex is better for bigger documents with a lot of images and citations. Is this still the case with the current version of word and software like Mendeley/Zotero?

For you guys what are the main advantages? Is it worth it even if you are the only one using it? How do you guys make the one around you to use Latex? How would with convince a colleague moving to Latex?

Comment: Maybe you should consider markdown and pandoc to write academic texts. You can also export word files. Yo could start reading up here: https://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2014/01/23/plain-text/ and here: https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html and, of course, here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=pandoc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I disagree with @DG's comment, sorry. Although learning Markdown is almost trivial, it's not suitable for academic writing. As for Pandoc, I think it's _more_ complicated than necessary to get the output you want. I would recommend reading [Overleaf's quick guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes) (it's far from complete, but it's a good start), and build knowledge from there. When I have to do collaboration works, I have to use Word. Any other document, short or long, I write with LaTeX, no second thoughts. Convincing others is trickier ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I've been routinely using pandoc for academic writing. Just, every time I don't know how  or plainly cannot do something in markdown, I escape to LaTeX.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik no need to be sorry. I think the question is too opinionated, to get a real answer here. And if it was up to me, I'd recommend ConTeXt. But more often than not, converts to (La)TeX have the institutional pressure to produce a word document and then they wind up here vulnerable and helpless. At least pandoc can remedy that a bit.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I agree in so far, that pandoc is a good start. At some point, you inevitable will feel the need to tweak the template or to 'escape' to LaTeX. It all depends on your needs. Still, if word is in the picture, the constraints of pandoc might be a blessing

Comment: Although I prefer LaTeX over Word and I’d say that LaTeX is much more stable (in terms of possible data loss due to software bugs) when it comes to really large text corpora, you should consider compatibility issues: If you are the only one using LaTeX and everyone else uses Word, you need to be tough!

Comment: The easiest way to hook a colleague on latex is is to do a team paper with them. Telling someone "all you have to do is type and all the formatting just happens" is, in my experience, convincing enough. Also having the bibliography auto-create itself in order just makes people go slack-jawed. And for getting bibliography information, almost every papers critical info can by gotten like so: `google schollar > search paper > click on the big quotation symbol > click bibtex > then copy that`. You will never have to type another citation ever.

Comment: For goodness sake don't convince people around you to use it if you're a PhD student. Do that and *you* will be the one expected to solve everyone's compilation problems. You might ask your department to arrange a workshop on using LaTeX or whether the university provides this. Then see if you can encourage people to go. But don't take on the burden of persuading directly, else they'll come to you when it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're really unlucky, you will even get desperate souls like me turning up at your door from other departments begging for help.

Answer (score 4):

The answer in brief:

## Yes

In a more detail:

- At least when I still cared, which was like, 15 years ago, Word was quite unstable for larger (100 pages an more) documents. Moving figures brought larger disasters, bibliography done wrong inflicted week-long suffering, etc.
- As mentioned in the comments, for most of the trivial things in LaTeX you can use Markdown, I recommend `pandoc`. Even if the whole setup seems not trivial, [there](https://medium.com/@krzysztofczarnecki/i-wrote-my-thesis-in-markdown-heres-how-it-went-3f60140dfe65) [are](https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown) [plenty of](https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown) [templates](https://github.com/s4ke/Master-Thesis), and I assure you, the invested time pays out.
- This might be disputable, but I (and many others) rather like the LaTeX optics of the final document. You can do some crazy stuff, such as the figures below. Start with `microtype` and continue as long as you want, it's a life long journey actually.
- You can much more easier use version control, such as `git`. I recommend this heavily, this way you can always track changes in your document. In a more reliable and easier way than with Word.
- Probably most important for academic writing: Automatic labels. All sections, figures, tables, theorems (if you have them) should get unique symbolic labels, such as `sec:introduction`. Then in the remaining text, you refer to those entities using such labels. The best thing: the numbering is automatic and if something is shuffled up, the labels get updated consistently. You won't believe me, how many man-years of work this feature saved me.
- Automatic citations with correct references style. Although eased by Zotero and Co., bibtex / biblatex / biber is there and ready to use without plugins.
- Automatic build system / continuous integeration: you can force your document to rebuild on every significant change, making sure it always works. It is a bit advanced software engineering tweak, but still worth it. Start with `latexmk` or `arara` and work up to `git` commit hooks and `make`, if it needs to be.
- LaTeX is old. Well, some bits are not *that* old, but most of it is. Which is splendid. Because, up to very exotic things, every mistake you will make already occurred to someone. There is already a solution out there for 99.9% of the problems you might have. This place is one of the sources to search for answers. In most cases I abort writing my question because there already have been answers – even if I get so far to write a question.
- Summarising, I might be indoctrinated, but LaTeX is (as far as I know) the easiest way of getting book-quality PDF of academic writing in least amount of time, especially if the document is large, i.e., a thesis.

[image: screenshot of my thesis]
[image: screenshot of my thesis]

Comment: You convinced me. But I am already a user. If your supervisor uses word. You are better off sticking to it. If the (top) academic journals of your field want word documents, even more so,

Comment: @DG' Possibly, but by no means necessarily. There are fields where LaTeX is a minority sport, but the minority wouldn't use Word for the world.

Comment: You can get automatic numbering and references with Word. You could do that when *I* last did serious work in it (or tried to - it kept chucking my work away so I gave it up). I also think that the bibliography thing is probably overblown now. Reference management software isn't so different. There's nothing builtin about bibtex or biber.

Comment: @DG' That one time the submission required Word, I wrote the paper in pure markdown (had to be careful) and got both Word and LaTeX from it.

Comment: @cfr Word seems to get better, yes. However, I stopped to care years ago. Bibtex belongs to the bundle, even if not strictly part of LaTeX the program, it's part of a TeX distro, which falls under the casual "use LaTeX". If you use, say, LuaTeX, it's also not "normal" pdfLaTeX, but still falls under the casual use of "TeXing" / "LaTeXing".